# Strategy using Higher Time Frame Security Function trades 1 bar late

Tags: pine-script

been using security function for multi-timeframe strategies in a while and would like to know if there is a solution to strategies trading 1 bar late.

As you can see in my script below, this simple strategy buys when the previous week's close > open and sells when vice versa. My issue is that it trades on Tuesdays instead of Mondays. I believe by Monday the information of the previous week is complete so it should be possible to trade on Monday based on that information.

Is it possible to solve this through security function or do we have to code the values of the weekly candle some other way?

Thanks in advance.

```
//@version=4
strategy("MTF Lag Issue", overlay=true)

weekly_open = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', open[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
weekly_close = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', close[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

weekly_red_candle = weekly_close < weekly_open
weekly_green_candle = weekly_close > weekly_open

weekly_candle_color = weekly_green_candle ? color.lime : weekly_red_candle ? color.red : color.gray

IsMonday = dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
IsTuesday = dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday

Long = weekly_green_candle
Short = weekly_red_candle


//PLOT
w_o = plot(weekly_open, linewidth=2, color=weekly_candle_color, style=plot.style_circles, title="Open")
w_c = plot(weekly_close, linewidth=3, color=weekly_candle_color, title="Close")

plotchar(IsMonday, title='M', char='M', location=location.abovebar, color=color.yellow, size=size.auto, transp=0)
plotchar(IsTuesday, title='T', char='T', location=location.abovebar, color=color.aqua, size=size.auto, transp=0)

//STRATEGY

strategy.entry('BUY', strategy.long, when=Long)
strategy.entry('SELL', strategy.short, when=Short)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
strategy("MTF Lag Issue", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = true)
```

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that this feature exists, it turns out I was still looking at Pine 3 reference all along.

Another question is it possible to make it trade at the open of the Monday bar?

Answer (score 0):

This is a version that will enter trades at the open of the beginning of the week. It doesn't use `security()`. You can flip back to the previous strategy in the script's *Settings/Inputs*. Be sure you validate it before using it pls. Comments explain some of the additions:

```
//@version=4
strategy("MTF Lag Issue", overlay=true)
useSecurity = input(false, "Use security as before")
showAbnormalWeeks = input(true, "Show abnormal weeks")
showWeekBoundaries = input(true, "Show Beginning and end of weeks")

IsMonday = dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
IsTuesday = dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday
// Correctly detects beginning of the week on any day.
WeekBegin = change(weekofyear)
// Detect end of week hoping it's a Friday but accommodate weeks with no Friday.
WeekEnd = dayofweek == dayofweek.friday or (WeekBegin and dayofweek[1] != dayofweek.friday)

// New open/close data.
var weekly_open = open
var weekly_close = close
if WeekBegin
    weekly_open := open
if WeekEnd
    weekly_close := close

// Previously used open/close data.
weekly_open2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', open[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
weekly_close2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', close[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

weekly_red_candle = useSecurity ? weekly_close2 < weekly_open2 : weekly_close < weekly_open
weekly_green_candle = useSecurity ? weekly_close2 > weekly_open2 : weekly_close > weekly_open

weekly_candle_color = weekly_green_candle ? color.lime : weekly_red_candle ? color.red : color.gray

Long = weekly_green_candle
Short = weekly_red_candle

//PLOT
w_o = plot(useSecurity ? weekly_open2 : weekly_open, linewidth=2, color=weekly_candle_color, style=plot.style_circles, title="Open")
w_c = plot(useSecurity ? weekly_close2 : weekly_close, linewidth=3, color=weekly_candle_color, title="Close")

plotchar(IsMonday, title='M', char='M', location=location.abovebar, color=color.yellow, size=size.auto, transp=0)
plotchar(IsTuesday, title='T', char='T', location=location.abovebar, color=color.aqua, size=size.auto, transp=0)
// Begin and end of week conditions.
plotchar(showWeekBoundaries and WeekBegin, title='WeekBegin', char='▲', location=location.belowbar, color=color.silver, size=size.tiny, transp=0)
plotchar(showWeekBoundaries and WeekEnd, title='WeekEnd', char='▼', location=location.belowbar, color=color.silver, size=size.tiny, transp=0)
// Show weeks with abnormal beginnings/ends.
bgcolor(showAbnormalWeeks and WeekEnd and dayofweek != dayofweek.friday ? color.red : na)
//STRATEGY

strategy.entry('BUY', strategy.long, when=Long)
strategy.entry('SELL', strategy.short, when=Short)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for this. Looking at the solution, does this mean that if I want to apply this logic to a different pair of timeframe, for example, 'D' and 1H, I need to alter the code each time depending on timeframe? Like maybe use dayofweek and hour instead?

I was hoping there was a more universal way to enter on the open of the beginning of a higher time frame bar.

Comment: Could be possible, but would require a more robust design. That code is just what I came up for your specific request; wasn't designing a generic solution.

Comment: Alright, if there is no built-in PineScript function or setting that can make that happen, then I'm assuming that a generic solution would be quite complex. Thanks for the info.